# Wrong arguments for CascadeClassifier detection

Tags: c++, opencv, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1

I work on CascadeClassifier MultiScale detection  for WindowsPhone 8.1 C# using Windows Runtime Component. 
Here is my code in WinRT:

```
cv::Mat mat(width, height, CV_8UC4);
cv::CascadeClassifier face_cascade;
face_cascade.load("haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml");
std::vector<Rect> faces;
 .
 .
 .
 .
equalizeHist(mat, mat);
face_cascade.detectMultiScale(mat, faces, 1.1, 2, 0, Size(30, 30));
```

And I still get error: 
error C2664: 'void cv::CascadeClassifier::detectMultiScale(cv::InputArray,std::vector<_Ty> &,double,int,int,cv::Size,cv::Size)' : cannot convert parameter 2 from 'std::vector<_Ty>' to 'std::vector<_Ty> &'

I follow the tutorial on OpenCV website and I do not why  my parameters should be wrong.

Thanks for reply.

Comment: please clarify: c++, not c# ?

Comment: this code is in WinRT in C++ and then I call methods to Windows Phone C# project

Comment: Maybe try `std::vector<cv::Rect> faces;` instead.

Comment: std::vector<cv::Rect> faces does not help me , still same error

Answer (score 1):

It should look like :

```
std::vector<cv::rect> faces; 
face_cascade.detectMultiScale(mat, faces, 1.1, 2, 0, cv::Size(30, 30));
```